# Get first character of previous line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Replace the first character of the current line with the first character of the previous line.
For example **Input** file:

```
Mark was
Great friend
And
```

**Output** file:

```
Mark was
Mreat friend
Gnd
```

Must be done with **`sed`**

I do not understand how to make the letter replace exactly the beginning of the word on the previous line, all I could do was add a character to the end of the line, but not to the beginning:

```
sed '2,$ s/[^.]/& &/; 2,$ s/ /\n/' file.txt | paste -d ' ' - -
```

Output:

```
Mark was G
Great friend A
And
```

I don't understand how exactly to specify in the regular expression to work at the beginning of the previous line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` is certainly the wrong tool for this!  But this seems to do what you want:

```
sed -e 1's/./&&/' -e H -e 's/\(.\).*/\1/' -e x -e 's/\n.//' input
```

On the first line, you duplicate the first character to prime the hold space.  For all lines, you append the line to the hold space (for this first line, this is the modified line with the first character duplicated).  Then you remove all but the first char and swap the pattern space with the hold space.  Then you remove the newline and the first character of the line, leaving the first character of the previous line and the remainder of the line in the pattern space, while only the first character is in the hold space.  Print the pattern space and repeat.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, if line number is more than 1 then print prev(which has first character of previous line) as first character and then print rest of line. And set each line's first character to prev variable to become first for its next line.

```
awk '
FNR==1{ print }
FNR>1 {
  print prev substr($0,2)
}
{
  prev=substr($0,1,1)
}
' Input_file
```

***OR*** more precisely:

```
awk '
FNR>1 {
  $0 = prev substr($0,2)
}
{
  prev=substr($0,1,1)
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1h;x;G;s/(.).*\n./\1/' file
```

Save the first line.

Swap to the copied line, append the current line to it, remove everything between the first character in the copied to the second character in the current line and print it.

N.B. The current line, now becomes a copy and the process repeats to end of file.

---

If each line always begins with a word of length two or more:

```
 sed -E '1h;x;G;s/\B.*\n.//' file
```